# My application freezes when I am loading a particular cell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I had an iPad application in which I am using iOS charts to draw two
graphs into the same tableview cell.

I am creating a view and adding the combined chart view inside that
view in the uitableview cell.

The issue is when I am trying to load that cell into my table the
application freezes.

I am just calling `[table reloadData]` and `scrollToIndexPath`. Nothing is in the background. All are happening in the main thread only. First I
am passing the number of section as 2 to hide this cell and on a
button click after changing a bool value I am reloading the tableview.

But the app is freezing in iOS 8.1. iOS 9.3 it was working fine. Can anybody help me on this to find where i am going wrong?

```
[mytable reloadData];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0
                                            inSection:2];

[mytable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Try to call `insertRowsAtIndexPath` than table `reloadData`. It may help.

Comment: as per new update on ios 9 it automatically calls willdisplay cell and manage well. but if you want explicitly manage in 8.1

Comment: @Pushp i didn't get u? the issue is if a add another cell in place of that everything working fine.surely some thing to do with UItableview cell i suppose.i am creating too many properties there in the tableview cell was that the reason?

Comment: Use the debugger. See where the app is freezing when you run under iOS 8.1.

Comment: @rmaddy that cell is surely creating pbm.how will i fetch the method name from pausing the Xcode.and looking at the left window.it only shows the threads.but actually how will i find the method in that threads.